# Delete all contexts Dialogflow from Android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, dialogflow-es

Base URL : https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/

DELETE 'https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/contexts?sessionId=12345'

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json

I'm using retrofit 2 and I want to make a delete request against Dialogflow. I want to delete all contexts.

This is what done so far :

```
@DELETE("contexts?sessionId=12345") Call<Void>deletDialogflow(@Header("Content-Type")String content_type, @Header("Authorization")String auth);
```

And in api call.

```
private void deleteContextDialogFlow(){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(DialogflowService.BASE_URL_DIALOGFLOW)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    DialogflowService service = retrofit.create(DialogflowService.class);

    Call call = service.deletDialogflow("application/json; charset=utf-8", DialogflowService.BEARER + DialogflowService.TOKEN_DIALOGFLOW);


   call.enqueue(new Callback() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {

           Log.e("Successful Delete", "" + response.body().toString());

       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

           Log.e("UnSuccessful Delete", "" + t.getMessage());


       }
   });



}
```

I have not got the result I want. That is, all contexts disappear.

Comment: can you give *YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN* to do test in postman ?

Comment: cecb575824d44f10834341a487375a9c

Comment: did you try in postman?

Comment: i get this error message in android studio when i try the execute the method. I got a 200 message in postman.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please whole code.

Comment: I have edit the question.

Comment: Please look at into my answer.

Comment: i get this when i try your code:

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call

Comment: I did update my answer

Comment: E/UnSuccessful Delete: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Look at my code it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did test below code working fine, look at this.[image: look at this]

Please take a look in my code carefully :

**DialogflowService.java**

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@DELETE("contexts?sessionId=12345")
Call<String> deletDialogflow(@Header("Authorization") String auth);
```

**deleteContextDialogFlow()**

```
Call<String> call = service.deletDialogflow(DialogflowService.BEARER+DialogflowService.TOKEN_DIALOGFLOW);
 call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.e("Successful Delete", "" + response.body().toString());
        }
        else{
        Log.e("Fail Delete", "" + response.errorBody().string());
        }

   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
       Log.e("UnSuccessful Delete", "" + t.getMessage());
   }
});
```